# Removing the featured image from the post but leaving it on the index page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following [blog post index page](http://www.the10and3.com). It loads a featured image before the text of the post.

On the [post itself](http://www.the10and3.com/the-hockey-map/) - I would like for the featured image to *not* load. I believe this involves editing this [content.php file (attached here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcff1t4vjytciqs/content.php?dl=0) but I cannot figure out how to do it such that the image loads only on the index page and not on the post page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in place of **the_post_thumbnail( 'serene-featured-image' );** at **line no 24**

Replace **line no 24** with below code:

```
<?php 
    if ( ! is_single() ) :
        the_post_thumbnail( 'serene-featured-image' );
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: @zgall1 the image can't visible to anywhere, because we add the server side condition. Can't getting you, and i think its working fine.

Comment: You are correct that it did work on mobile. I am guessing I was looking at a cached version of the site.

Comment: After further experimentation with your suggestion, I don't think it works. There are two problems, one of which is serious. When I change the code, the header (menu and social media buttons) are no longer links if a featured image is added. Also, if a word in the headline is too long to fit onto a line, it is broken up with a hyphen rather than placed on the next line. When I removed your code and reverted to the previous code, neither of these issues were present.

Comment: Please clear your question first, because this code is for only featured image it doesn't effect to any other code.

Comment: It definitely did even if I don't know exactly why. I commented out the code you suggested and replaced it with your code. The features described above broke. I then added back in the original code and everything worked as expected. At this point, it doesn't matter because I have gone elsewhere to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this code in your `single.php` (Deatil page of the Blog post)

```
<div class="main-image<?php if ( '' == get_the_post_thumbnail() && 'video' === get_post_format() ) echo ' et_video_only'; ?>">



<?php if ( 'video' === get_post_format() && false !== ( $first_video = et_get_first_video() ) ) : ?>
    <div class="et-video-container">
        <?php echo $first_video; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( ! is_single() || ! 'video' !== get_post_format() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="et-main-image-link">
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'serene-featured-image' ); ?>

        <?php serene_post_meta_info(); ?>

    <?php if ( isset( $first_video ) && $first_video ) : ?>
        <span class="et-play-video"></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( ! is_single() || ! 'video' !== get_post_format() ) : ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- .main-image -->
```

Comment: Here is the entire file:

`<?php
/**
 * @package Serene
 * @since Serene 1.0
 */

get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;

comments_template( '', true );

get_footer(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find all the occurrences of function `the_post_thumbnail` and remove them.
Interesting files are:

1. single.php
2. page.php
3. content.php
4. content-gallery.php
5. content-audio.php
6. functions.php

Also check for `get_the_post_thumbnail`